# How to make "Computers" files in Google Drive sync to multiple computers?

Tags: google-drive

In Google Drive there are these two items in the sidebar, "My Drive" and "Computers"

The contents/files in the "My Drive" is synced through all my computers, laptop, and desktop alike.

However, the "Computers" section is not synced on both computers.  When one computer gets broken there's no way for the files in Google Drive "Computers" section to sync locally (which I have tested) and it just stays online.

Is there a way to sync the files from "Computers" in any new machine I have in case one computer gets lost?

Comment: If one of your computers is lost/broken, you can download your synced folders from the [_Computers_ section on the Google Drive website](https://drive.google.com/drive/computers)

Comment: So that means, the only option is to manually download and no way to sync, downloading zips the whole folder and if the folder is too big, then the only way is to download one by one

Comment: No, if you enable Google Backup and Sync to synchronise your Google drive with 2 PCs (not the Computers section), that folder will be synced on all your computers just like any other file or folder in your Google drive. If, for some reason, you cannot change the location of the folder on the computer, simply add a symlink/hardlink in the Google Drive local folder to the folder to be synced.

Comment: If you already have a folder that has been synced from a PC in your drive _Computers_ section, just move it to your _My Drive_.

Comment: If you move files from *Computers* section then it will consume storage space unlike if you put it only in the *Computers* section and enable High-Quality upload so videos will not consume storage quota, this is the reason I put files in the Computers section only.